# Solving equation containing Erf expressions

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions

Given the equation below, how do I find the value of `b` so that the function is equal to 21. I tried solve but I keep getting an error message.

```
(15 Sqrt[π] (Erf[11 Sqrt[b]] + Erf[17 Sqrt[b]]))/(14 Sqrt[b]) == 21
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: This title is uninformative.  Please re-write the title to be of use to someone trying to use these solutions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Solve, if you specify constraint on `b`

```
  eq = (15 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Erf[11 Sqrt[b]] + Erf[17 Sqrt[b]]))/(14 Sqrt[b]) == 21;
  Solve[eq && 0 < b < 100, b]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

First there is a typo in your equation, it should be Sqrt[Pi] and not Sqrt[[Pi]]. This equation can not solved via NSolve, but you get a result (approx 0.0325) via FindRoot:

```
FindRoot[(15 Sqrt[Pi] (Erf[11 Sqrt[b]] + Erf[17 Sqrt[b]]))/(14 Sqrt[
  b]) - 21, {b, 1.}]
```

Comment: I do not believe that `Sqrt[\[Pi]]` is incorrect.

Comment: Uuups, seems as I need new glasses ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FindInstance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) to find one solution:

```
N@FindInstance[(15 Sqrt[Pi] (Erf[11 Sqrt[b]] + Erf[17 Sqrt[b]]))/(14 Sqrt[b]) == 21, {b}]
```

> ```
> {{b -> 0.0325472}}
> ```